# Getting (key, value) pairs from a HashMap using an iterator

Tags: java, android

I have

```
private Map<K,Collection<V>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

I want return the value

```
public Iterable<Map.Entry<K, V>> allValues() {
}
```

How could I return the values as Iterable?

Comment: Choose a language

Comment: The map holds values of type `Collection<V>` and `allValues()` should return an `Iterable` with map-entires with values of type `V`. How should the `Collection<V>` be *transformed* to `V`?

Comment: Say you have a map `{x: [y, z], a: [b, c]}` then do you want to return an iterable that gives the pairs `(x, y), (x, z), (a, b), (a, c)`? If so, you should edit your question with this kind of example.

Comment: You will absolutely have to implement the `Iterable` interface yourself.  (You could also choose to use a library that does something like this, like Guava's `Multimap`.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use streams as follows:

```
Iterable<Map.Entry<K, V>> iterable = map.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(v-> entry(e.getKey(), v)))
    .collect(toList());
```

This assumes Java 9 or above (for [Map.entry](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V))) and the following static imports:

```
import static java.util.Map.entry;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```

Comment: You can just use `Map.entry` rather than going to `AbstractMap`.